# invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘uint8_t’ Arduino

Tags: types, arduino

I'm trying to set the pin mode for all Analogue input pins at once on my Mega. So I made an array before set-up:

```
char* Analog_Input_List[16] = {"A0","A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8","A9","A10","A11","A12","A13","A14","A15"};
```

Then I tried to run this:

```
 //analogue input pin set-up
 for (int i =0;i<8;i++){
 pinMode(Analog_Input_List[i], OUTPUT);   
 }
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
sketch_jul24a.cpp: In function ‘void setup()’:
sketch_jul24a.cpp:54:40: error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘uint8_t’
sketch_jul24a.cpp:54:40: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void pinMode(uint8_t, uint8_t)’
```

I'm new to arduino programming and the declaring and manipulation of types keeps confusing me I'm aware its something simple but not sure how to go about fixing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The pins you are trying to initialize are described by preprocessor macros expanding to integer constants. They are not strings. What you want instead is

```
int inputPins[] = { A0, A1, /* etc. */ };
```

instead.

Comment: @user2137452 Please accept my answer if it helped. Also, see my comment - you should really learn C at least to a basic level before programming the Arduino.